# DROWN CVE-2016-0800 Patch Missing on Centos 7

Tags: openssl, cve, centos

My security admin is worried that my OpenSSL version does not contain a patch for DROWN (`cve-2016-0800`).

I ran a yum update and have installed the latest Centos 7 OpenSSL: `openssl-1.0.1e-51.el7_2.5.x86_64`

When I check the changelog using `rpm -q --changelog openssl-libs | grep 2016` I have recent CVE fixes but not one for 2016-0800.  Is the official Centos 7 OpenSSL really still vulnerable?  If not how can I prove my install is valid?

Is it possible that the RPM I got is mistagged?  If so how do I get its checksum and where can I verify it against an rpm release?

I realize there are tests specifically for DROWN but this is one example among many other missing CVEs and I don't to be on the hook to individually test each one.

Comment: RedHat back port security fixes. OpenSSL fixed DROWN in the 1.0.1 version in 1.0.1m. RedHat take the fix from 1.0.1m and apply it to 1.0.1e. So I think you do have the fix, and your security admin is incorrectly saying 1.0.1e is vulnerable. Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure this is correct on your system, so please check a little more :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm 99% sure I do have the fix but due to politics I need a way to prove that the fix is there (and an easy way to prove that the other missing CVEs are also there).

Comment: You can use the RedHat security advisories to show that - they include both the RedHat package versions and the fixed CVEs.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Red Hat security advisory for that CVE](https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2016-0800), RHEL 7 is not affected.  If you follow the [article in the external references](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2176731) to another [security advisory](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016:0301), you'll see it says:

> Note: This issue was addressed by disabling the SSLv2 protocol by default
>   when using the 'SSLv23' connection methods, and removing support for weak
>   SSLv2 cipher suites. For more information, refer to the knowledge base
>   article linked to in the References section.

Answer (score 0):

I realized what I was really looking for was: https://github.com/OpenSCAP/openscap

It should scan and verify that my system's RPMs are up to date with any CVEs.